# How do I displaying "0" event when database is empty with ".length"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Quick one, please how do i display "0" even though my database is empty - `{cart !== null ? cart.order_items.length : 0}`, this only works when i put something in the database, which then reads 1, 2,3 then 0 if i delete them, but the initial case it shows "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cart.order_items.length')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is as follows:

```
{cart && cart.order_items ? cart.order_items.length : 0}
```

A shorter way of doing this is `{cart?.order_items?.length || 0}`.

You want to be sure that `cart` is defined, and so also `cart.order_items`, before accessing the `cart.order_items.length`, or you may end up getting another error about `cart.order_items` not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If it returns undefined then check for `undefined` in the condition also

```
{cart !== null || cart !== undefined ? cart.order_items.length : 0}
```

You should try not check in the negative way, so it would be like this:

```
{cart && cart.order_items ? cart.order_items.length : 0}
```

Even better/shorter, you can use `?.` [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and `||` operator:

```
{cart?.order_items?.length || 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Undefined is not null, instead of your evaluation be "!== null" you should something like:

```
{!cart ? 0 : cart.order_items.length }
```

I exchanged the order of the evaluation, because I don't know what the database would return that could evaluate as true, it could be a message or sort of like that, that's the reason why I've changed the order.